# difference between Dataset and TensorDataset in pyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

what is the difference between "torch.utils.data.TensorDataset" and "torch.utils.data.Dataset" - the docs are not clear about that and I could not find any answers on google.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Dataset` class is an abstract class that is used to define new types of (customs) datasets. Instead, the `TensorDataset` is a ready to use class to represent your data as list of tensors.

You can define your custom dataset in the following way:

```py
class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Your code

    self.instances = your_data

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return self.instances[idx] # In case you stored your data on a list called instances

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.instances)
```

If you just want to create a dataset that contains tensors for input features and labels, then use the `TensorDataset` directly:

```py
dataset = TensorDataset(input_features, labels)
```

Note that `input_features` and `labels` must match on the length of the first dimension.